# Is this recursive template typedef-ing valid C++?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I'm having a little problem when compiling a program of mine which uses (or attempts to use) some sort of "recursive" template definition. Let me try giving an example.

Say I have class `A` which is a container of some sort, and `Filter` classes which provide "filtered" iterators over collections (some elements are skipped based on a predicate, much like Python's generators with an `if` keyword).

Let's define `A<int>` which contains integers, and `PositiveFilter<A<int>>` which can be iterated on and will skip any negative element in the `A` instance. If we take this program:

```cpp
A<int> foo = {-1, 0, 1}; /* Let's assume I can init. this way */
PositiveFilter< A<int> > positives(foo);
for(auto const i : positives) std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

The output will be:

```
0
1
```

Let's note that both the `A` and `Filter` classes can be iterated on. Given this, I assume we can define the following function...

```cpp
template<typename Iterable>
void bar(Iterable& c) {
    for(auto const i : c) std::cout << i << std::endl;

    /* TODO: randomly change the sign of elements in c */

    typedef PositiveFilter<Iterable> SubPositiveFilter;
    SubPositiveFilter foo(c);

    /* Let's assume iterator difference is properly implemented in filters */
    if(std::distance(foo.begin(), foo.end()) == 0) return;
    bar(foo);
}
```

... and later do something like...

```cpp
A<int> foo = {-1, 0, 1};
bar(foo);
```

... and watch my code run until randomness gets tired of it.

Basically what I'm interested in is this recursive defining of `PositiveFilter`s over `PositiveFilter`s over `PositiveFilter`s [...] over `A`s. I reckon I may have made a few mistakes in my code (things going out of scope, typing mistakes, ...) but if we can put that aside, **I'd like to know whether this "recursive" typedef-ing of filters over filters is valid**.

I have tried doing it in the context of a bigger program, but `g++` started taking all my CPU time. Coming back to the example above, my theory is that it is trying to define...

```
A<int>
PositiveFilter<A<int>>
PositiveFilter<PositiveFilter<A<int>>>
PositiveFilter<PositiveFilter<PositiveFilter<A<int>>>>
...
```

until my computer crashes from the infinite loop. In my case, the problem occurs when using COIN-OR's LEMON graph library, which provides graph adaptors allowing me to iterate over specific elements of a graph. In a function, I am recursively defining adaptors over adaptors until a certain stop condition is met in the subgraph. For those familiar with Boost's Graph library, a similar concept is available (filtered graphs).

Could anyone give me more details about this?

Comment: Whether it's "valid" or not depends entirely on the template itself. There is no law that says that they're always valid, or always invalid.

Comment: Yes, your template produces an infinite recursion at compile time because any instantiation would require (potentially) infinitely-recursive types. Instead of this approach, I would probably go for a single `Filter` template type holding a unary boolean predicate, and then provide means to compose filters. Or just use [range](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) / [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/libs/range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that your function doesn't stop its recursion "at compile time", so even if `std::distance(foo.begin(), foo.end()) == 0`, `bar(foo)` need to be instantiated.

And so it has to instantiate

- `bar<Iterable>`
- `bar<PositiveFilter<Iterable>>`
- `bar<PositiveFilter<PositiveFilter<Iterable>>>`
- ...

Several work-around are possible:

- Don't modify a positive typed range into invalid range. Modify only original range. pass only original range to your function.
- Modify your filter so that applying twice the filter doesn't change the type:
  -> `PositiveFilter<PositiveFilter<Iterable>>` is `PositiveFilter<Iterable>`.

Comment: I ended up making a few other changes which dissipate the issue, but it's not far from your second workaround in the end. Thank you! I had no idea such loops could occur at compile-time (or expected gcc to have some sort of watchdog against them). Then again, template programming is not my forte.